# Complete metric space question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a non empty and complete metric space and $f:X \to X$ is a contraction. Show that there exists exactly one $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Why do you say it is stupid?

Comment: I wanted to say it was stupid of me to ask this question as it is nothing but Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: It is not stupid, it is a very important theorem, and there is nothing stupid questions about important theorems..

Comment: I know. That's not what  I meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) or Contraction mapping theorem. For the proof see the link.